# Running ident on Android/HTC

Tags: applications

Our Business intranet uses [ident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ident_protocol) to get user credentials for the different programs/modules. Our programmers say they cant/wont change this. I'm wanting to use one of the programs on my HTC Android phone, but it wont let me use the web page as it picks up my ident as "unknown" rather than "helen". I've tried various IRC apps which say they run ident, but none of them seem to work, unless I've got them set up wrong. e.g. Sock server ultimate.
Any ideas how I can get ident running on my phone?

Answer (score 0):

[BusyBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox) (requires root) includes [fakeidentd](https://www.freshports.org/security/fakeident/), which is an extremely simple Ident service that just replies to everything with the same username.

```
127|root@X9076:/storage/sdcard0 # fakeidentd --help
BusyBox v1.23.1-Stericson (2015-02-06 13:50:32 EST) multi-call binary.

Usage: fakeidentd [-fiw] [-b ADDR] [STRING]

Provide fake ident (auth) service

    -f      Run in foreground
    -i      Inetd mode
    -w      Inetd 'wait' mode
    -b ADDR Bind to specified address
    STRING  Ident answer string (default: nobody)
```

So in your case, you would simply run `fakeidentd helen` from a shell on your device (such as with [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm)).